# Name of text describing an action in a play

Tags: italics

I'm trying to find the name of an element of playwriting which describes actions performed by actors in a play. For example,

> Let me see.
>
> *Picks up skull*
>
> Alas, poor Yorick!

The element I'm referring to here is "*Picks up skull*". Does this have a name? If so, what is it?

Comment: Those actions are described by the author (or, as in the case of your example, by an editor) to be performed by the *characters*. Actors do what they damn well please.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Stage direction — as mentioned in [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/stage+direction).

When the play is actually staged, as StoneyB says:

> The action itself is called business in The Profession, unless it involves movement from one location to another, when it is called a *cross*, verb *to cross*. All business and crosses together constitute *blocking*; the director (producer in GB) blocks the play, with as much or as little fidelity to the writer's stage directions as he likes.

Comment: +1 The action itself is called *business* in The Profession, unless  it involves movement from one location to another, when it is called *a cross*, verb *to cross*. All business and crosses together constitute *blocking*; the director (producer in GB) *blocks* the play, with as much or as little fidelity to the writer's stage directions as he likes.

Comment: @StoneyB: that should be its own answer or added to the current one.

Comment: @Mitch Up to Luke if he wants to use it. What he provides is a complete Answer to OP's Question; I just provide footnotes.

Comment: Seemed like the question was more broad than that, but that's all good info, Stoney, I'll add.

Comment: Luke you seem to have not noticed the style formatting there.

Comment: Did not. Fixed. Thx.

Comment: Actually _director_ is increasingly common in the UK as well, though people in more traditional non-professional groups still say _producer_.

Comment: @ColinFine Thanks. I've been out of The Profession for nearly 20 years now, so my jargon's dated. But then most theatre slang is centuries old.